# How to upload image from one domain to another?

Tags: codeigniter

I have two domain one is stgportal and another is stg.I want to upload image from stgportal to stg.My code is given below

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ThumbnailImage']['tmp_name'],"http://stg.eminencesystem.com/assets/images/th/".$thimg)
```

show the error: `failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections`

how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURL to send file to another server securely like this

At stgportal side

```
function sendImageToServer($path = "", $file = null)
{

    $post_url = "http://stg.eminencesystem.com/post_file";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    //most importent curl assues @filed as file field
    $post_array = array(
        "folder_name" => $path
    );
    if ((version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5') >= 0)) {
        $post_array['file'] = new CURLFile($file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, TRUE);
    } else {
        $post_array['file'] = "@" . $file;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

At stg side

```
$ImagePath = "/var/www/html/assets/";
$files = $_FILES;
$folder_name = utf8_decode($_POST['folder_name']);
$savepath = $ImagePath . $folder_name . $files['name'];
copy($file['tmp_name'], $savepath);
echo 1;
exit;
```